# How to invoke Guava's Table class from another class

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, invoke

I have a two dimensional arraylist which specifies a group of number with several rows and columns. But I encounter some problems when I'm doing a method in another class which is used for calculation, the method needs to use the numbers in the array but I fail to invoke them.

Here's the error message: `Syntax error on token "SRate", delete this token
                    - The method get(int) is undefined for the type SIBOR`

The way I invoke is like `arrayname.get(row)arrayname.get(column)`

Comment: If this is an array, why are you doing `arrayname.get()` instead of `arrayname[i]` or better yet `arrayname[i][j]`?

Comment: @JohnB If I try so, it gives me this error `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<SIBOR>`

Comment: So it is not a two-dimensional array as you state. Please update your question to be more specific. `ArrayList<SIBOR>` is one-dimensional so row vs column doesn't make any sense. FYI, you might want to check out Guava's Table class.

Comment: Provide the necessary code. @JohnB because OP's using `ArrayList`, not array.

Comment: @JohnB so if my coding has different rows and columns, it is an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there is no such thing as a two-dimensional arraylist. You can have a `List<List<SIBOR>>` but that is termed a `List of Lists`. You would access this via `arrayListName.get(i).get(j)` as long as you KNOW that `i` exists in the outter list otherwise this will result in a `NullPointerException`.

You can also do:

```
List<List<SIBOR>> outter = ...;
List<SIBOR> inner = outter.get(row);
SIBOR value = inner == null ? null : inner.get(column);
```

The trick with a `List of Lists` is that on insert you need to check if the inner `List` exists and if not create it.

Again, I will point out that Guava's [Table](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) class is exactly what you need and will prevent the need to create inner `Lists` or get an NPE if the outter list doesn't exist.

So instead of `List<List<SIBOR>>` you would have `Table<Integer, Integer, SIBOR>`. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I have already changed the title of the question and NOW I'm going to explore Guava's Table!

Comment: And btw as for hashbasedtable or treebasedtable, which one would be more suitable for my coding?

Comment: And since I have 12 columns for each row, is it still okay for me to use Guava's Table? Sorry for asking so much :(

Comment: If you have a fixed number of columns and rows, I think I would use ArrayTable: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayTable.html

Comment: Yes, you can have any number of columns or rows. Table will take care of it all for you.

Comment: Finally, since you should not be getting the same error (or if you do something else is going on). I would suggest you should close this ticket as answered. If you are still having issues, create a new ticket.

Comment: Okay sure! But I am not so sure how to close this ticket:( Can you teach me? LOL

Comment: select "check" next to answer that is correct. If you found other answers as helpful, up-vote them.

Comment: Oh I thought need to literally close this ticket :) Done! Thx for your selfless help!

Answer (score 0):

Array is NOT ArrayList!

Accessing array:

```
arrayName[i];
```

Accessing ArrayList:

```
arrayListName.get(i);
```

Comment: If my coding has rows and columns lik `{x,x}, {x,x}`, what it would be? Thank you for your kind help.